# CSS / jQuery change animation duration of a rotating element

Tags: jquery, css

I need to change the animation duration of a rotating wheel. This is working in every browser I have tried it on desktop, except Safari and all iOS browsers.

The classes are applied and removed from the element but the animation duration doesn't change after the first one is called. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

```js
let speed = 0;
$('.spinner').addClass(`rotate-${speed}`);

$('.speedUp').on('click', function() {
  if (speed <= 2) {
    $('.spinner').removeClass(`rotate-${speed}`);
    speed += 1;
    $('.spinner').addClass(`rotate-${speed}`);
  }
})

$('.speedDown').on('click', function() {
  if (speed >= 1) {
    $('.spinner').removeClass(`rotate-${speed}`);
    speed -= 1;
    $('.spinner').addClass(`rotate-${speed}`);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 36px;
}

div.spinner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px dashed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.rotate-0 { animation: rotate 0s linear infinite; }
.rotate-1 { animation: rotate 4s linear infinite; }  
.rotate-2 { animation: rotate 3s linear infinite; }
.rotate-3 { animation: rotate 2s linear infinite; }
```

```html
<h2 class="speedUp">+</h2>
<h2 class="speedDown">-</h2>
<div class="spinner"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors in the browsers which don't behave as you expect?

Comment: I have but it doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari is an idiot browser sometimes - You "need" to make it re-render the element by hiding is for a split second, and showing it again.

The below snippet should work fine in safari

*EDIT*. Now I say "Need", but there obviously might be workarounds, that I am not aware of..

```js
let speed = 0;
$('.spinner').addClass(`rotate-${speed}`);

$('.speedUp').on('click', function() {
  $('.spinner').hide();
  if (speed <= 2) {
    $('.spinner').removeClass(`rotate-${speed}`);
    speed += 1;
    $('.spinner').addClass(`rotate-${speed}`);
  }
  setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.spinner').show();
    }, 50);
})

$('.speedDown').on('click', function() {
  $('.spinner').hide();
  if (speed >= 1) {
    $('.spinner').removeClass(`rotate-${speed}`);
    speed -= 1;
    $('.spinner').addClass(`rotate-${speed}`);
  }
  setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.spinner').show();
    }, 50);
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 36px;
}

div.spinner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px dashed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%          { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
    100%        { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0%          { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
    100%        { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

.rotate-0 { 
    -webkit-animation:rotate 0s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation:rotate 0s infinite linear;
    animation: rotate 0s linear infinite; 
}
.rotate-1 { 
    -webkit-animation:rotate 4s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation:rotate 4s infinite linear;
    animation: rotate 4s linear infinite; 
}
.rotate-2 { 
    -webkit-animation:rotate 3s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation:rotate 3s infinite linear;
    animation: rotate 3s linear infinite; 
}
.rotate-3 { 
    -webkit-animation:rotate 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation:rotate 2s infinite linear;
    animation: rotate 2s linear infinite; 
}
```

```html
<h2 class="speedUp">+</h2>
<h2 class="speedDown">-</h2>
<div class="spinner"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If your animation stops - your brower was not fast enough to make the transitions in 50ms - make that 100, and the animation should work again.